# How to create an alias to a report manager url

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

We just changed from SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services to SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services.

The report manager url for the new SQL Server instance is different from the old one.

Is there a way I can map the new url to the old one so that people can still access the new reports with the old url???

Example :

Old url :

```
     db02/Reports
```

New Url :

```
     db2012/Reports.
```

We don't use the old server anymore and I would like to map that url to the new url

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following possible options:

1. Preferable option: in your DNS server add an alias named "db02" that points to IP address of the new "db2012" host (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168322)
2. Add a mapping in the hosts file (located in C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc), but this you will need to do on all client machines.